# Duplicate Download All cached Object Firebase 3x, Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, firebase, download, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I use Firebase to download all Image to Gallery. After downloaded, It's automatically cached and for being used later, but when I upload new image, Firebase automatically download the whole database again + cached Objects are still there that leads my app to crash. This is how i get downloadUrl from database.

```
DataService.instance.UsersRef.child(userUID).child("NewImage").observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
            if let snap = snap.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snap {
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        print(key)
                        print(postDict)
                        let originImage = Gallery(postKey: key, postData: postDict )
                        self.image.append(originImage)
                    }
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collection.reloadData()
            }

        })
```

This is located in ViewDidLoad, I try replace .value with childadded but It couldn't get any new database. I want to load all image in the gallery when user first use, but later when new comes, it should load and get just the new one. This is my download code.

```
func configureCell(gallery: Gallery, img: UIImage? = nil) {

    self.image = gallery
    if img != nil {
        self.OriginImage.image = img
    } else {
        // UrlImage.append(image.imageUrl)
        let ref = DataService.instance.OriginImageStorageRef.storage.reference(forURL: image.imageUrl)
        ref.data(withMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Unable to download from Storage")
            } else {
                if let imgData = data {
                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                        cache.setObject(img, forKey: self.image.imageUrl as NSString)
                        print(cache.object(forKey: self.image.imageUrl as NSString))

                        self.OriginImage.image = img

                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }



}
```

And this is in mycollectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let image = self.image[indexPath.row]
    let img = cache.object(forKey: image.imageUrl as NSString)
    print(img)

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCell", for: indexPath) as? ProfileCell {

        if let img = cache.object(forKey: image.imageUrl as NSString) {
            cell.configureCell(gallery: image, img: img)
        } else {
            cell.configureCell(gallery: image)
        }


        //self.image.removeAll()
        return cell

    } else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

}
```

When I use ChildAdded, it doesn't return Dictionary as .value, this is what I get when I use .childAdded

```
Optional(1)
Optional(2016-09-23T05:32:11.412Z)
Optional(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/capabdsjsad-     a837b.appspot.com/o/x4BL06rXbrOBXnZXLE57ea1WUsU2%2FOrigin%20Image%20Cap%2F59C4F818-946B-414C-9E87-CD3B8C3F47C8?alt=media&token=4d1151e3-2362-4fd6-a9d1-9891bb913887)
```

It works well without new data in Firebase, even new data comes, collectionView will show all cached object and download the whole data from database again, not the newest one. I guess it should be because of I work with Firebase in the wrong way, not because of the cache. I work with it in more 2 days and really can't find the way to solve it properly. It re-download everything in the database again, which causes the problems. If anyone have any idea, I am very appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: You should, as you mentioned in your post, be using child added for this. It downloads initial data and updates when new records appear. Narrow the scope of this question to the correct one:  Why doesn't your child added event work? And post exactly the amount of code needed to reproduce that, with version info and sample data.

Comment: The problem is I located .value in ViewDidLoad, When I take picture and go to page, It calls ViewDidLoad again. Where should I put .value for just being called one when people first go to the app.